# fwrite.data.table and `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` format optimization with fixed UTC offset

Tags: r, optimization, data.table, lubridate

I'd like to use R `data.table`'s `fwrite` to output DateTime values in YYYY-MM-DD hh:nn:ss format (in the non-DST abiding ETC/GMT+8 timezone), rather than the default (ISO 8601) YYYY-MM-DDThh:nn:ssZ format, where some timestamps have fractional seconds which I want to round to the nearest second.

Using `lubridate` I've been able to use `fread` to read in the dates, then use a `x:=with_tz(x, "Etc/GMT+8")`, followed by `x:=force_tz(x,"GMT")`.

However, with my test data set (6.5 million entries of 12 columns), I have mostly slow solutions, and am looking for a better way to go about things. I don't wish to use `fwrite(..., dateTimeAs="write.csv")` as that would ignore the fixed UTC offset in favor of local time.

(Various solutions moved to my "answer" below)

Any other optimizations that you can think of?

Comment: replacing the `,force_tz(with_tz` construct with ,setattr((as.double(dtc)-28800),"class",c('POSIXct','POSIXt')) seems to have sped things up quite a bit for that portion of my code upstream of what is shown here

Answer (score 0):

### Best Solution to Date: base-R + data.table + fasttime

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
# above this point: set d_f and o_f to valid file paths

totTime<-proc.time()
install.load <- function(package.name)
{
  if (!require(package.name, character.only=T)) install.packages(package.name)
  library(package.name, character.only=T)
}
pp<-function(...) {
  print(paste0(...))
}
ISO2Human<-function(x) {
  ot<-substr(x,1,19) # ignore fractional seconds and "Z"
  substr(ot,11,12)<-" "
  if(anyNA(ot)) ot<-substr(x,1,10)
  return(ot)
}

install.load('data.table')
install.load('fasttime')
pp("parameters read and libraries loaded: ",timetaken(totTime))

main <- function() {
  dat<-fread(d_f,fill=TRUE)
  # notably dat has a "d_utc" column in YYYY-MM-DD hh:nn:ss format
  pp("data file Read: ",timetaken(totTime)) # 5.200sec

  # A fair amount of code is inserted here. Highlights include
  #   1. As computations appear to be faster in double/numeric form 
  #      than POSIXct (and starts as character), I adjust it as follows:
  #        dat[,d_utc:=setattr(fastPOSIXct(d_utc,tz="GMT"),"class","numeric")]
  #   2. dat gets merged with another DT using foverlaps, producing fo (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/53858287/4228193)
  # as we resume code, 8.690sec have elapsed

  # As my target timezone is UTC-08:00 (POSIXct ETC/GMT+8), I subtract 28800 seconds.
  # But to protect against a rounding error in the double type
  # (and because I have some fractional second data that I want to round)
  # I add 0.5 to this value.
  fo[,d_pst:=setattr(d_utc-28799.5,c("POSIXct","POSIXt"))][,d_utc:=NULL]
  pp("timestamps adjusted to PST (UTC-08:00): ",timetaken(totTime)) # 16.8sec
```

---

This is the particular portion of code I tried to optimize in this question;
but in doing so, I discovered some of the type conversions used above seemed more optimal.

```
  tf<-tempfile()
  fwrite(fo,file=tf)
  fo<-fread(tf)
  # fread reads in as character, not timestamps
  # POSIXct's as.character and format calls are much slower than fwrite + fread (!!!)
  fo[,DetectDate:=ISO2Human(DetectDate)] 
  # this truncates seconds, effectively rounding due to the previous adjustment of 0.5s
  unlink(tf) # delete file
  pp("coerced to string: ",timetaken(totTime)) # 26.9sec
```

---

```
  fwrite(fo, file = o_f, quote = FALSE)
  pp("output file written: ",timetaken(totTime)) # 27.1sec
  # aren't SSDs awesome?
}
main()
```

## Other solutions

Lubridate-based block (no temp file). Times at the top are mm:ss

```
# 01:17
j<-copy(fo)
tt<-proc.time()
j[,c("dd","dt"):=IDateTime(d_pst, ms="nearest")]
# if adding 0.5 seconds, trunc rather than nearest
j[,d_pst:=paste(dd,dt)][,c("dd","dt"):=NULL]
timetaken(tt) # 1:17
j
j[,lapply(.SD,class)]
rm(j)
```

base-R POSIXct conversion to string using as.character or format

```
# 01:02
j<-copy(fo)
tt<-proc.time()
j[,DD2:=format(DetectDate,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")]
timetaken(tt) # 1:02
j
j[,lapply(.SD,class)]
rm(j)
```

base-R implicit conversions to character + splicing date and time

```
# 12:36
j<-copy(fo)
tt<-proc.time()
j[,DD2:=paste(lapply(DetectDate,substr,1,10),lapply(DetectDate,substr,12,19))] 
timetaken(tt) # 12:36
j
j[,lapply(.SD,class)]
rm(j)
```

base-R, avoiding lapply (silly me)

```
# 02:29
j<-copy(fo)
tt<-proc.time()
j[,DD2:=paste(substr(DetectDate,1,10),substr(DetectDate,12,19))]
timetaken(tt) # 2:29
j
j[,lapply(.SD,class)] # just to confirm our target column is character
rm(j)
```

data.table + base-R, but using data.table's tstrsplit and paste, rather than grabbing a range of characters

```
# 00:24
j<-copy(fo)
tt<-proc.time()
tf<-tempfile()
fwrite(j,file=tf)
fo2<-fread(tf)
fo2[,c("compDate","compTime","compMS"):=tstrsplit(DetectDate,"[TZ.]")][
    ,DD2:=paste(compDate,compTime)]
unlink(tf)
timetaken(tt) # 0:24
fo2
fo2[,lapply(.SD,class)]
rm(j,tf,fo2)
```

basically the optimal solution, although re-using variable and field names, cuts this down to 10s

```
# 00:14    
fap<-function(x) {
  ot<-substr(x,1,19)
  substr(ot,11,12)<-" "
  if(is.na(ot)) ot<-substr(x,1,10)
  return(ot)
}
j<-copy(fo)
tt<-proc.time()
tf<-tempfile()
fwrite(j,file=tf)
fo2<-fread(tf)
fo2[,DD2:=fap(DetectDate)]
unlink(tf)
timetaken(tt) # 0:14
fo2
fo2[,lapply(.SD,class)]
rm(j,tf,fo2,fap)
```

I'm using a(n) SSD, which probably greatly speeds up the temp file solution vs a "standard" setup