# is foverlaps deterministic with mult="last" (or "first")?

Tags: r, data.table

This question is somewhat related to github issue [#1617](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1617) of `data.table`

I would like to use `data.table`'s `foverlaps` function match dates to within a range, but only match it to the range that has the greatest end date (which would also be, by the structure of my data, the largest range of dates as start date should be the same for all matching intervals for a given `Rx_ID`).

Here is the relevant code snippet

```
setkey(dat, Rx_ID,    eventtime,    duptime)       # eventtime = duptime (POSIXct)
setkey( sl,    Rx, Rx_UTC_Start, Rx_UTC_end)       # Rx_UTC_end > Rx_UTC_Start (POSIXct)
fo<-foverlaps(dat, sl, type="within", mult="last")
```

---

Questions

1. Will the `mult="last"` guarantee that it picks the `Rx_UTC_end` that is greatest for a given `Rx_ID`&`Rx_UTC_Start` pair, as it is part of the key for `sl`?
2. Is `foverlaps` the correct function to use, or should I just use a straight-up non-equijoin, given the duplication in date stamps in `dat` to satisfy `foverlaps`
3. What would I do if I wanted to use `foverlaps` to find the greatest (or least) value in some other column of `sl` rather than `Rx_UTC_end`?

   - Would I have to use `mult="all"` and sort the results, then eliminate rows with lesser values in my targeted column?
   - Or would `foverlaps` sort in the order of any `setindex` indices that I have for `sl`, despite the index operation not reordering the data in `sl` itself? Then I would use `mult="last"` restriction.
   - Or is there a way to have 4 keys for `sl` and 3 for `dat`? In this scenario with the third-from-last column in `sl` would be a spectator to the join, but used to sort `sl` and the post-`foverlaps` `fo` prior to the `mult` restriction.

Comment: This is not an answer, but I personally always found `foverlaps` to be non-intuitive to use, so have stopped using it once non-equi joins were introduced.